# fire function after toggle

Tags: jquery, function, toggle

I can't figure out why this is not working.
I'm just trying to scroll the .toggle container to top after the .toggle-box finsihed the animation.

```
jQuery(".toggle").click(function(){
    jQuery(".toggle-box").slideToggle(), function() {
        jQuery("html,body").animate({scrollTop: jQuery(".toggle").offset().top}, 500)
        };
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to pass the scrolling callback as an argument to the `slideToggle` function:

```
jQuery(".toggle").click(function(){
  jQuery(".toggle-box").slideToggle(function() {
    jQuery("html,body").animate({scrollTop: jQuery(".toggle").offset().top}, 500)
  });
});
```